# What CSS classes to use to make LWC look properly on home page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, css, home-page-component

One of the items on the Lightning home page is this:

[image]

What CSS classes must I use to make my own LWC look like such a standard home page component? I can fool around with h1, h2, b, etc., to imitate the looks, but it seems to me there should be CSS classes that I can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to look at [SLDS's Card Component](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/#site-main-content) or [lightning-card](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card). Using the built-in component would be ideal unless you have specific needs that are not met with that component.

Comment: Yes, that works, the code examples for the Card Component helped me.